# Flextable label not created in rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, flextable

I am using `flextable` to produce tables for a pdf document rendered with `rmarkdwown`. I want to cross-reference the tables, but they do not produce the label needed for the cross reference to work.

#### My Minimum Reproducible Example

What follows is the content of the file `test.Rmd`:

````
---
title: "document title"
author: "author here"
date: "2022-01-20"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    fig_caption: yes
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
    latex_engine: xelatex
    keep_tex: true
---

```{r, include = FALSE}
library(flextable)
library(bookdown)


opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, out.width = "85%", fig.align = "center")

```

```{r, tab.id = "anyTable", tab.cap = "Invented data", tab.lp = "tab:"}

a = data.frame(id = LETTERS[1:3], x = 1:3)

flextable(a) |> theme_vanilla()
```

```{r secondTable}

b = data.frame(id = LETTERS[4:6], x = 4:6)

flextable(b) |> theme_vanilla() |> set_caption(caption = "This is secondTable")
```

# Standard rmarkdown crossreference

Trying anyTable: \ref{tab:anyTable}.

Trying secondTable: \ref{tab:secondTable}.

# Bookdown crossreference

Trying anyTable: \@ref(tab:anyTable).

Trying secondTable: \@ref(tab:secondTable).
````

Contents of `header.tex`:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contenidos}
\captionsetup[table]{name=Tabla}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Figura}
%\usepackage{float} #use the 'float' package
%\floatplacement{figure}{H}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
\newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
```

When I do `rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd", output_file = "test.pdf")` the file is rendered in pdf, but the following warning comes out:

```
Output created: test.pdf
Warning message:
LaTeX Warning: Reference `tab:anyTable' on page 1 undefined on input line 198.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `tab:secondTable' on page 1 undefined on input line 20
0.
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

If I check the .tex file, I can see that the captions are there, but they do not have the labels. The relevant lines of the intermediate `test.tex` file:

**lines 106 to 109**

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{0.75in}|p{0.75in}}

\caption{Invented data
}\\
```

**lines 153 to 156**

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{0.75in}|p{0.75in}}

\caption{This is secondTable
}\\
```

I expected that the caption line in the tex file was something like `\caption{This is secondTable}\label{tab:secondTable}\\`

#### What I've tried

- Changing latex engines (lualatex, pdflatex, xelatex).
- Editing the tex file (adding the label after the caption), but it fails to convert to dvi with multiple errors (mostly "undefined control sequence")

#### What am I doing wrong?

How can I cross-reference the tables produced by flextable?
Alternatively, I am open to other packages you may suggest. As some of the headers in my real data are somewhat complex (multi-span headers and the like), I would like to steer away from `kable` and `kableExtra` if at all possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a format from bookdown to get cross references, see https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/cross-ref.html

````
---
title: "document title"
author: "author here"
date: "2022-01-20"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2: 
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
    latex_engine: xelatex
    keep_tex: true
---

```{r, include = FALSE}
library(flextable)
library(knitr)
library(bookdown)

opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, out.width = "85%", fig.align = "center")
```

```{r, tab.id = "anyTable", tab.cap = "Invented data"}
a = data.frame(id = LETTERS[1:3], x = 1:3)
flextable(a) |> theme_vanilla()
```

```{r secondTable}
b = data.frame(id = LETTERS[4:6], x = 4:6)
flextable(b) |> theme_vanilla() |> set_caption(caption = "This is secondTable")
```


# Bookdown crossreference

Trying anyTable: \@ref(tab:anyTable).

Trying secondTable: \@ref(tab:secondTable).
````

[image]

Comment: Fextable is great. @David Gohel thanks for an awesome package!